Fix IntelliJ IDEA Gradle Sync Failed For Old Module
Sometimes when I'm modifying some projects I get old modules leftovers, like when trying to sync my project I get this error:

It has issues when syncing my gradle project because of an old module that I removed from my project structure, but when syncing IntelliJ tries to also sync the deleted module.

In order to fix (or in this case remove leftovers) your old modules, you have to open and edit the file $PROJECT/.idea/gradle.xml. This file will contain a section called GradleProjectSettings, look for the one you don't need. In my case I already deleted the api/ module but IntellIJ was still trying to sync it, I'll just remove the selected line and done :)

After that you can try again and sync your project, and see there's no more errors.

